# Is this a bad idea/practice what problems would I run into

Tags: c#

I have a process that I need to make into a service. This process runs autonomously right now so there are no concerns with user interaction I just need to "turn" it into a service. I got to thinking about it and decided that I could just create a service that launched the process, this would give me the added benefit of having outside control of the process.. I could watch it for an unexpected exit and re-launch it.. I could also watch its memory usage and kill it if it gets out of hand. I dont think I have seen many other applications do this and I was thinking there must be a reason why so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to add complexity.

Instead of just having the process exist, you'll now need to make a second executable to "launch and monitor" this process.  This adds overhead (the service and process both running), adds complexity, and makes life as a whole a bit more difficult.

That being said, if you've got a .NET Console application, turning it into a service is incredibly trivial.  Your `Main` routine basically just gets moved into a method, and launched in a thread.  Once you do that, the service application is effectively done - it's just configuring the service (which can be done in a designer) and overriding `OnStart` to spin up a thread and call your routine.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good idea, but you've reinvented the wheel. What you're thinking of is essentially server monitoring. There are several high-quality open source implementations of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything that you can do this way you can do with less complexity by just putting the application logic in the service.  Not to mention that you get Service Recovery for free by doing it in the service directly.